# Converting a string containing both char's and int's into an integer in C

Tags: c, string, integer, ascii

Say I have the string (represented as a char pointer) given from a strSHA2 hash of a file:

```
"f731d405b522b69d79f2495f0963e48d534027cc1852dd99fa84ef1f5f3387ee"
```

How could I effectively turn it into an integer? Is there any way to cast it? atoi() terminates as soon as it reaches a char.

Would iterating through and converting char's using arithmetic such as `letter - 'a'` be the best way?

I intend to use it as an index for a hash table, thus need an integer.

Length of the integer would be the standard 32bit for C

Comment: um, is this a hex string? What you're describing makes no sense otherwise. but if that's the case, clearly `atoi` is not the function you need (assuming you've read any atoi documentation). What is the "integer value" of "7ee" according to you?

Comment: That looks like *hexa-decimal*, and `atoi` can't handle it. `atoi` also can't handle anything but `int` which typically is a 32-bit signed integer type. And there's no standard integer type large enough for that number. So what is the data really representing? Is it supposed to be a series of bytes? Something else? Where did you get the data from? What does that source tell you about the data?

Comment: it's a strSHA2 hash.. I intend to convert the hash into an integer index for a hash table :)

Comment: Please confirm you want to transform this into a 256 bit integer, and/or clarify.

Comment: That's just too long to be stored as an integer

Comment: I have clarified, 32-bit integer, as is the default with C

Comment: Ignoring the fact that the string you're looking at is actually a representation of a 256-bit integer, you *could* just treat it as a string, and hash it that way.  Two quick, easy, popular (and not very good) string hash functions are: (1) Loop over each character in the string, add up the character values, take the resulting sum modulo some number N. (2) Loop over each character in the string, accumulating the Exclusive OR of all the character values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probaly want to transform the hexadecimal number made of the first 8 chars of the SHA2 string into an unsigned integer (32 bit) which sounds like a pretty good hash function to me as it is pretty unlikely that two different sha2 hashes start with the same 8 bytes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned int GetHashValueFromSHA2String(const char *sha2string)
{
  char first[9];
  memcpy(first, sha2string, 8);  // copy first 8 chars of sha2 string
  first[8] = 0;                  // null terminate
  return strtoul(first, NULL, 16);
}

int main()
{
  unsigned int hashvalue = GetHashValueFromSHA2String("f731d405b522b69d79f2495f0963e48d534027cc1852dd99fa84ef1f5f3387ee");
  printf("Hashvalue = %08x", hashvalue);
}
```

Or even simpler:

```
unsigned int GetHashValueFromSHA2String(const char *sha2string)
{
  unsigned int value;
  sscanf(sha2string, "%8x", &value);
  return value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to convert a hexadecimal string to a 32-bit unsigned integer data type, you can use the function [`strtoul`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtoul).

However, a 32-bit unsigned integer data type is only able to represent numbers up to 2<sup>32</sup>-1, which is insufficient in your example of a 256-bit number.

Therefore, it would only be possible to convert this number into eight 32-bit integers.

However, as pointed out in one of the other answers, it does not make sense to use a 256-bit index into a hash table. Since you can probably assume that all of the bits of a SHA-2 hash are sufficiently uniformly distributed for your use-case, it should be sufficient to simply take the first 10 or 16 bits of the SHA-2 hash and use them as an index into your hash table. That way, your hash table would have a length between 8 KiB or 512 KiB, assuming 8 bytes per hash table entry.

Comment: no you can't. Neither `long` nor `long long` will be large enough to store that integer.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Yes, you are right. I believe I have corrected my answer.

Comment: "unsigned int" isn't always 32 bit.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Yes, you are right that ISO C only requires it to be 16 bits wide. However, Linux, Windows and MacOS all define it as 32 bits. I'm not sure what the situation is on embedded systems, though. Therefore, I have removed all references to `unsigned int` and replaced them with `32-bit unsigned integer data type` or something similar. I could have simply used `uint32_t`, but I'm afraid that referencing fixed-width integer types would be more confusing than helpful to OP.

Answer (score 1):

> Say I have the string (represented as a char pointer) given from a strSHA2 hash of a file:

That is then a hexadecimal representation of a 256 bit integer.

Your computer doesn't have a 256 bit integer type, so you can't cast that, possibly.

Instead, you'll want to use a different function from your hashing library that doesn't give you a printable string, but just 32 bytes of raw hash data. You can then use, say, the upper 2 bytes as hash table indices.

Using a 32 byte (256 bit) hash table index makes no sense – no computer in this world has enough memory for a table with 2²⁵⁶ entries.

Honestly, however, if you want a hash table, use an existing hash table instead of building your own.

Comment: I intend on converting the integer into the index for the table using simple arithmetic (integer * PI % hashtablelength).

Comment: um, that's just another level of hashing, and an especially bad one, too. doing that instead of just using say the upper four byte as integer has no advantage - by construction, your hash's upper four bytes are even more random than the output of your arithmetic operation. So, don't. Really, don't build a hash table yourself at your level of insight!

Comment: for example, SHA2 as hash for a hash table: um, unless you have **very** good reasons to pick **exactly** that, I'd assume that's not a good choice.